# Problem replacing words using [^a-zA-Z] regex

Tags: java, regex, replace

Just could not get this one and googling did not help much either..

First something that I know: Given a string and a regex, how to replace all the occurrences of strings that matches this regular expression by a replacement string ? Use the [replaceAll()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method in the String class.

Now something that I am unable to do. The regex I have in my code now is [^a-zA-Z] and I know for sure that this regex is definitely going to have a range. Only some more characters might be added to the list. What I *need* as output in the code below is **Worksheet+blah** but what I get using replaceAll() is **Worksheet++++blah**

> ```
> String homeworkTitle = "Worksheet%#5_blah";
> String unwantedCharactersRegex = "[^a-zA-Z]";
> String replacementString = "+";
> homeworkTitle = homeworkTitle.replaceAll(unwantedCharactersRegex,replacementString);
> System.out.println(homeworkTitle);
> ```

What is the way to achieve the output that I wish for? Are there any Java methods that I am missing here?

Comment: Thanks everyone !! [^a-zA-Z]+ worked just great.. Overlooked that fact - my bad !

Comment: Just want to recommend http://regexpal.com/ where you can visually test your regexps. It is admittedly in javascript, but for not too complicated expressions it should work the same as in java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[^a-zA-Z]+
```

Will do it nicely.

You just need a [greedy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) in order to match as many non-alphabetical characters you can, and replace the all match by one '+' (a - by default - greedy quantifier)

Note: `[^a-zA-Z]+?` would make the '+' quantifier lazy, and would have give you the same result than `[^a-zA-Z]`, since it would only have matched only one non-alphabetical character at a time.

Comment: Just a quibble: You don't really need a "greedy" pattern as much as you need a <i>quantifier</i>--saying one or more  occurrences--which are by default greedy.

Answer (score 2):

```
String unwantedCharactersRegex = "[^a-zA-Z]"
```

This matches a single non-letter. So each single non-letter is replaced by a +. You need to say "one or more", so try

```
String unwantedCharactersRegex = "[^a-zA-Z]+"
```